# My expo react native project won't build because of Gradle Build failed with unknown error

Tags: react-native, expo, build.gradle, build-error

This is the error. I states something about the react-native-camera:

[image: This is the error. I states something about the react-native-camera]

I tried inserting these to the build.gradle file of my project but it did nothing:

[image: I tried inserting these to the build.gradle file of my project but it did nothing]

[image]

Also, the gradlew command won't work even if I already have gradlew. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)